# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Login issue

Tags: 14.04, login, lts

After restarting my PC, I am not able to see my users on screen. Only the guest session appears, but I am not able to log in. When I click on the guest session login, screen turns black and returns to the login screen.

Comment: try to use `ALT+F2` login your user `startx`

Answer (score 0):

You could use alt+F2 and log into your account using the command line. I've experienced this once and did that to log in. This is only temporary though, you won't get your login screen right doing this, but you will probably at least be able to log into your account.